# SublimeText - Few commands missing from command palette

Tags: sublimetext2

I was trying some plugins on my Sublime Text yesterday and today I noticed that some commands were missing form my command palette window, namely:

- New file into view (Not "new view into file", that one is still there)
- Open in Browser as Testing `Server`(maybe the word "server" here is wrong)
- Open in Browser as Development `Server`(maybe the word "server" here is wrong)

These three were really helpful to me, How can i get them back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These commands are added by a package called `SideBarEnhancements`. Install this package and you will get these commands back.

#### [SideBarEnhancements on GitHub](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements)

Comment: You have any idea about the command for layout columns thing, in pallete?

Comment: @akshay You can use Origami for that

Answer (score 0):

sublime text menu is a json PATH_TO_SUBLIME\Data\Packages\Default\Main.sublime-menu you can edit it or replace

Comment: I can't see anything even remotely related to those three commands in `Main.sublime-menu`.

Comment: try download new sublime and replace only that file

Comment: I accidentally removed `SideBarEnhancements` plugin. Those 3 (and many more) commands were added by that plugin